# Splitting group of items using regex in java?

Tags: java, regex

This my string:

```
String="if((A>B)||(C<D)) Result;"
```

I need split into like this `A>B,||,C<D,Result`

Output should be like  `A>B,||,C<D,Result`

Comment: What's your criteria for splitting? Do you just want to remove all occurences of `if` and brackets? Or do you want to grab out the operand to `if` and split it up into operands and logical operators?

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear what you want to do, maybe its better you explain it a bit more and also the background why you want to do it.

Of course you can split on each character (sequence) you don't want to have, but then there is still the "if" in the result:

```
String s = "if((A>B)||(C<D)) Result;";

String[] r = s.split("[()| ;]+");
for (int i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Item " + i + ": " + r[i]);
}
```

Will result in

```
Item 0: if  
Item 1: A>B  
Item 2: C<D  
Item 3: Result
```

Comment: MySting = "if (((param5 > param6) || (param7 < param8))) (exp4 + exp5);"

Comment: MySting = "if ((param1 > param2) || (param3 < param4)) (exp1 + exp2);" Use Regular expression and Pattern class.    My Output should be  :                                                     item o: param1 > param2                                          item1: ||                                                      item3: param3 < param4                                         item4: exp1+exp2

Comment: You still haven't explained what you want your regular expression to extract...Assuming you want all expressions in brackets and all logical operators, then try the above `s.split("[() ;]+]") in @stema's answer above. And then ignore `r[0]` since it contains `if`.